# ASP MVC Routing of root directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

We have multiple web applications deployed on the same server needed to communicate to each other. For example, there are 2 applications deployed in wwwroot folder of IIS: Foo and Bar.

The problem is: from a FooView.cshtml view in the Foo web application, I need to call to **MyAction** of the **Test** controller from the **Bar** web application.

For now we have to hard-code the url like this:

`<a href="\Bar\Test\MyAction?id=100">Test action</a>`

How to define it in the route config so that we can use method like Url.Action or Url.Route to call the action? Thanks in advance.

Comment: And you can't merge this applications and use [areas](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/714356/Areas-in-ASP-NET-MVC) then?

Comment: I'm not sure it makes sense to use `@Url.Action` if it's for an action in another application.  It's not using the standard routing within the application that you're coding within, it's a link to elsewhere as far as the application is concerned.  You could easily create your own HTML helper to link to it if you do it frequently.

Comment: @teovankot: I know this but they are separate applications so we cannot merge into one. :)

Comment: @PhucVD well, then i gess there are no way, becose you cant use `RouteConfig` from different application easy. Offcorse you can create library with Common `RouteConfig` and create your own `HtmlHelper` like @Coulton advice but i can't see many pluses in this approach.

Comment: @Coulton: I agree, Url.Action may not support this but I think we can use other method plus some configuration.

Comment: Hopefully the code I've provided in my answer could help and save you the pain of repeating the same code over and over if you use it frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to use `@Url.Action` or `@Html.RouteLink` if its to create a link for an action that exists outside of your application.

The helpers make use of the routing information that exists within your application and produces relative links accordingly.  The route configuration explicitly restricts external URLs fro being defined within a route.

You could easily create your own HTML helper to link to it if you do it frequently:

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc.Html
{
    public const string ExternalAppName = "externalapp";

    public static class ExternalHelpers
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString ExternalLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string externalPath, string linkText)
        {
            var tb = new TagBuilder("a");
            tb.MergeAttribute("href", Path.Combine("/" + ExternalAppName + externalPath));
            tb.SetInnerText(linkText);

            return new MvcHtmlString(tb.ToString());
        }
    }

    // Accepts a controller and action
    public static MvcHtmlString ExternalLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string controller, string action, int id, string linkText)
    {
        var tb = new TagBuilder("a");
        tb.MergeAttribute("href", Path.Combine("/" + ExternalAppName + "/", controller + "/" + id.ToString()));
        tb.SetInnerText(linkText);

        return new MvcHtmlString(tb.ToString());
    }
}
```

View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@Html.ExternalLink("/home/index", "Click to go to external app!")
```

Comment: Thank you :). This is a good solution, we can add one more parameter for the external app name to make it more flexible. But I find that we still have to pass a manually constructed url for the controller, action and route parameters (if any).

Comment: You could create a variation on this method that accepts a controller and action if you wanted to.  I've added an example to the answer.